# Is there a way to migrate my wordpress blog to another website that uses a different domain?

Tags: migration, blog

I'm currently running a blog page for our company that utilizes Wordpress.
The blog was created after we finished working on our official company website, which utilizes a different domain.

Here's the situation summed up:

1. Blog created through Wordpress, using the domain **name.blog**
2. Company website created by developers (Google Cloud), using the domain **named.do**

We were hoping if there is a way to migrate our blog (name.blog) to our main company website (name.do) as a subdomain/subdirectory (e.g. name.do/blog).

Extra notes:

- I didn't set up any third-party hosting services when creating this wordpress site. Till this day, I'm not aware of any hosting services that I'm using for the blog.
- Our company website is hosted on Google Cloud, and is generally managed by our software developers

Any comments or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are both websites WordPress website or just one? If both, you can enable the multisite feature and just export all your blog posts and import them in your main WordPress installation.

Comment: Well the website has to be hosted somewhere, and you're going to need to found out where or it's not going to be possible to move it. When it comes to moving it, there's documentation for that here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/#moving-directories-on-your-existing-server The full process will depend entirely on how the Google Cloud website is built and managed, so you're not going to get much help here (unless it's also WordPress).

Comment: The company website is not wordpress - it's coded manually by our developers and is hosted on Google Cloud. 

The blog website is wordpress. Would I have to find information on Google Cloud's website?

Comment: Yes. A “Google Cloud hosted website” could be literally anything, so you’re going to need to ask the people who built the company website. This isn’t something anyone here is going to be able to help with.